# can i send function key to unix server through telnet

Tags: ios, unix, networking, telnet

I want to access unix server on my iPod and this is almost done and i am able to send and receive data from server but when i send a function key (F1, F2,...) to server, server sends me same value that i have sent.

For example : F1 as key code is `\e[OP` .
My code for this-

```
SignedByte functionKeyEscSeq[5];
    int index=0;
    functionKeyEscSeq[index++]='\e';
    switch (keyCode) {
        case 0://Done
            [self unhideAllDefaultButtons];
            break;
        case 1://F1 //PF1 Key
            functionKeyEscSeq[index++]='O';
            functionKeyEscSeq[index++]='P';

            break;
        .....
     }
     [self sendByte:functionKeyEscSeq toIndex:index]; // Method to send this byte array with socket connection
```

My Question : Is it possible to send function Key to Server.
If it is possible then please send me some reference or format by which it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

As far I know, you must set your telnet terminal type as TERMINAL_TYPE=vt200 in order to send function keys.

Comment: yes i have already set this, at the time of negotiation process.

Comment: Are you sure you are sending also the  \n or \r ?

Comment: right now we are not sending any \n or \r, just sending code.

Comment: now i am add \n at end of key code but still not working.
server send me: 
`psh: /eOP: not found - try help for commands`

Comment: nice, I don't see where you put [ in your functionKeyEscSeq... Nevermind, did you try to send a \eOQ ?

Comment: i have got same result from \eOQ also.
can you send me data that you have got from \eOQ?